# Hundreds of plots with R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have quarterly forecasts and actual values for 141 numeric variables, measured for 3 different countries. I would like to find out for which variables my predictions are "good enough". As I am doing some early exploration, I am trying to plot actual values and forecasts, for each of the 3 * 141 = 423 couples (country, variable). I do not know how to make that many plots with ggplot2.

I have melted the data frame with all variables, so it now has columns:

```
 $ Date    : 'yearqtr' num  2017 Q1 2017 Q2 2017 Q3 2017 Q4 ...
 $ Country : Factor w/ 3 levels "CN","DE","US": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 141 levels "BCU_D","BUSCONFM",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 $ value   : num  21382 56639 45900 71196 -34100 ...
 $ isActual: logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
```

Then, I have tried a simple call with ggplot:

```
ggplot(meltedData, aes(x = Date, y = value, color = isActual)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(Country ~ variable, ncol = 3) + scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", n = 5)
```

What I get is a few useless, grey boxes.

I would like to get 141 * 3 graphs as described above.

I was thinking making a 141 page pdf document, with one set of plots for each variable by page, would be an option, if that is easier.

Thank you!

===========

The solution suggested by @Gregor (looping through variables) was satisfying:

```
for (this_variable in unique(meltedData$variable)) {
  g = ggplot(meltedData[meltedData$variable == this_variable, ],
             aes(x = Date, y = value, color = isActual)) +
               geom_line() +
               facet_wrap(. ~ Country, nrow = 3) + 
               scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", n = 5) + 
               labs(title = this_variable)
  ggsave(filename = paste0(this_variable, ".png"), plot = g, path = "output_graphs")
}
```

Comment: use `facet_grid` instead of `facet_wrap` for two variables. Reconsider if you really want 141 x 3 plots on a single pdf page...

Comment: The `ggforce` package has a paginated version of the `facet_wrap()` and `facet_grid()` which might be convenient when plotting that amount of variables.

Comment: @teunbrand, it looks like an interesting package. Checking [the documentation for the paginated version of facetgrid](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggforce/versions/0.1.1/topics/facet_grid_paginate), it seems to me we would still need to use a for loop, so the final solution resembles Gregor's: we would loop through page numbers instead of looping through variables, but the principle is the same. Am I right?

Comment: That sounds about similar to what I understood from the documentation. I'd suppose it would has a small benefit of having consistency (e.g. same axis limits every page), but if your axes are free that wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`facet_wrap` (or `facet_grid`) will give you one grid of plots - you won't be able to do page breaks between rows. With 141 rows, your option would be to create a *very* tall image file, probably too unwieldy to use.

A better approach would be to save each row (or set of rows) to a different file. Since I don't have your data, I can't test solutions, but here's an example using built-in data:

```
library(ggplot2)
for (i in unique(mtcars$cyl)) {
  g = ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == i, ], aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ am) +
    labs(title = paste("Cylinder:", i))
  ggsave(filename = paste0("cylinder_", i, ".png"), plot = g)
}
```

On your data, I think it would look something like this (untested):

```
for(this_var in unique(meltedData$variable)) {
  g = ggplot(meltedData[meltedData$variable == this_var, ],
             aes(x = Date, y = value, color = isActual)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap(~ Country, ncol = 3) +
    scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", n = 5) +
    labs(title = this_var)
  ggsave(filename = paste0(this_var, ".png"), plot = g)
}
```

Comment: It was a good idea, thank you very much. I have included the final solution in the initial post. I modified it lightly: for example, I loop over variables instead of countries, as I have only 3 countries but too many variables to put all of them in only one image.

Comment: Ha! My oversight there. Glad you got it working. (I edited the answer as well)